# Mocking of a nested list as @RequestPart in JUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a Rest Controller for which I need to write JUnit in a Springboot application. Below is the code for the same

```
@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
public void update(
        @PathVariable(name = "id") Long id,
        @RequestPart List<List<Long>> affectedIds,
        @RequestPart String compatibility,
        @RequestPart(name = "procId") String procId,
        @RequestHeader(value = "timeZone") String timeZone) {

    TimeZone userTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
    myService.update(
            id, affectedIds, compatibility, Long.parseLong(procId), userTimeZone);
}
```

I tried writing the JUnit for which below is the code

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Mock
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void update() throws Exception {

        Long id = 123L;
        List<List<Long>> affectedIds = List.of(
                List.of(1L, 2L),
                List.of(3L, 4L)
        );
        String compatibility = "oncecompatible";
        String procId = "11";
        String timeZone = "UTC";

        TimeZone userTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);

        doNothing().when(myService).update(id, affectedIds, compatibility,
                Long.parseLong(procId), userTimeZone);

        ObjectMapper mapper = createObjectMapper();
        String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(affectedIds);

        ResultActions response = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put
                ("/api/proc/check/update/{id}", id)
                .content(s)
                .content(compatibility)
                .content(procId)
                .header("timeZone", timeZone)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));

        response.andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

    private static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

The thing is that when I run this test case I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'affectedIds' is not present.
```

I have tried different other ways but not a success. I am not able to get how to send the **affectedIds** parameter in the mock request.

> P.S. - I have used the createObjectMapper() as per the suggestion from one of the articles of stackoverflow.

Comment: What value is in `selectedAffectedTupleIds` in the test? And related, what about the variable `affectedIds`? Should that be used on the request?

Comment: I have changed the code..the place where `selectedAffectedTupleIds` has been changed to `affectedIds`.  The `affectedIds` contains a `List<List<Long>>` as it is clear from the code block. Also, it is further used in the service so it is used in request.

Comment: Do _not_ mix `@SpringBootTest` and `@Mock`/`@InjectMocks`. It's really time for a canonical question about this, there are far too many questions with this misconception

Comment: How should Spring know that `content(…).content(…).content(…)` maps to the three request parts? You never specify a name. You cannot chain them, each invocation overwrites the value of the previous call.

Comment: And since you are annotating your inputs with `@RequestPart` ("Annotation that can be used to associate the part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument."), why do you then make a request with `application/json` as content type (`contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)`)?

Comment: cont'd I assume `procId` and `procedureId` should be the same variable in your test (otherwise, the test does not compile). Gven they are, you are only sending the JSON body `11` to your endpoint (the number 11)

Comment: It would be very helpful to include how you expect your endpoint to be called. With a JSON payload or with a multipart/form-data payload? Perhaps include a working `curl` call for your running application, then it is possible to help/suggest a working test setup.

Answer (score 0):

You must *not* mix `@SpringBootTest` and `@InjectMocks`/`@Mock` annotations. If you do, Spring (and thus MockMvc) will be unable to find and use use the correct beans. Also, you don't need to extend with `SpringExtension`, `@SpringBootTest` already takes care of that.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired    // <- wire from application context
    private MyController myController;

    @MockBean     // <- register mock bean in application context
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    // ...
}
```

Other issues with the given code:

- `.content(s)` overwrites any content previously set. Multiple calls are *not* additive. Your controller only receives the payload `11` (without quotes; the quotes are part of Java's syntax).
- `@RequestPart` is for `multipart/form-data` requests only, but in your test you set content-type to `application/json`.

Comment: I am not able to get your solution. My question is totally different and what you are saying is completely off the track. Even if I change it how is it possible to pass a `List<List<Long>>` in the mock request. Please go through the question thoroughly once. Also, I took your suggestion and changed the code accordingly but no result..I am still getting the same error mentioned in problem statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot @knittl for your inputs!! Indeed, it is a valuable feedback which you gave me for the `content(s)` thing. Can you please tell how to resolve this so that I can proceed further? If you need anything, from my end please let me know!!

Comment: @shikharsaxena all the requests for clarification are directly under your question, you only need to answer them

Comment: Hey @knittl, This is the url it is of localhost as we are running tests locally
`http://localhost:8080/api/proc/comp/updateRa/1`. Also, in the payload tab under the heading of FormData, these three parameters are there
`affectedIds: (binary)
compatibility: ONCECOMPATIBLE
procId: 2`
Can you help now??

Comment: @shikharsaxena I don't know what the "payload tab under the heading of FormData" is. Please go carefully through all comments under your questoin one by one, make sure you understand them, then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76967863/edit) to add the necessary details as formatted text as requested by each comment.